# Getting all the children of a parent using MSSQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchy

I have the following data in my database:

```
Parent      Child
101         102
101         103
101         104
101         105
101         106
```

My parameter is 106. And using the parameter I want to retrieve all the other children under its parent which is 101. I tried using the recursive method but it didn't work given the following data. Is there another way to formulate a query?

Answer (score 16):

Assuming you want to get *siblings* of the value `@p0`, you can use a simple self-join:

```
SELECT p.Child
FROM Table1 c
INNER JOIN Table1 p ON c.Parent = p.Parent
WHERE c.Child = @p0
AND p.Child <> @p0
```

The not-equal clause here makes sure you get siblings not including the value you searched for. Remove it as necessary.

[SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/84902/4)

---

Since you mention recursion though, perhaps you want the *entire tree* starting at the parent of the value `@p0`. In which case, you can use a recursive CTE:

```
WITH parent AS (
    SELECT Parent
    FROM Table1
    WHERE Child = @p0
), tree AS (
    SELECT x.Parent, x.Child
    FROM Table1 x
    INNER JOIN parent ON x.Parent = parent.Parent
    UNION ALL
    SELECT y.Parent, y.Child
    FROM Table1 y
    INNER JOIN tree t ON y.Parent = t.Child
)
SELECT Parent, Child
FROM tree
```

SQL Fiddle examples [using your data](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/84902/6) and
[with additional data to demonstrate the recursive CTE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fa26a/1)

Comment: siblings? But he wrote "Getting *all* the **children** of a parent..." How can I get all the sub-tree of a given value (parent) - root of a sub-tree?

Comment: @alessadro and by definition your parent's other children are your siblings?

Comment: Siblings are in the same "level", like brother. I'm wrong?

Comment: @alessadro That's right. The sample data also only had one level. If you want the entire tree starting at the given id's parent, take a look at the second half of this answer.

Comment: I use phpMyAdmin with MariaDB and it have not the "WITH" function :(

Comment: @Ic. could you tell me the MariaDB equivalent? please.

Comment: Very nice - elegant solution.

Answer (score 7):

SQL Authority has a blog with a very nice explanation of how to perform a Hierarchical Query using a Recursive CTE

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/24/sql-server-introduction-to-hierarchical-query-using-a-recursive-cte-a-primer/

Regards

Answer (score -1):

```
select child
from my_table T1
where exists (select 1 from my_table T2 where child = @parameter and T1.parent = T2.parent)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
WITH parent AS (
    SELECT Parent
    FROM Table1
    WHERE Child = @p0
), tree AS (
    SELECT x.Parent, x.Child
    FROM Table1 x
    INNER JOIN parent ON x.Parent = parent.Parent
    UNION ALL
    SELECT y.Parent, y.Child
    FROM Table1 y
    INNER JOIN tree t ON y.Parent = t.Child
)
SELECT Parent, Child
FROM tree
```