# Filemaker: Build a text from text fields in child rows

Tags: filemaker

My Filemaker app wants to display a text build up from filtered child rows. It should be displayed in a scrollable text field in the layout of the parent row.

Essentially, I have a tree structure where each node contains a paragraph or two of text.
In the layout of any node, I want to display its own text plus the text of all its descendents.
But since these are text fields which can be one or more paragraphs long, the usual list view doesn't satisfy me, as it doesn't expand to show the full text, only one line. Also, it only shows the direct descendents.

I want to show the full text of all descendents, and pick two text fields from them - a headline (optional field) and the main text.

I'm new to Filemaker. Tried to google for an answer to this but could not find anything that fits. Finding the related rows is easy enough, but I can't figure out how to display them in the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to display your related texts in a portal, since you want to indicate which ones you want to use. Make your portal rows tall enough for your needs and use a scroll bar on the text field if needed. You would need to gather all descendants in one table occurrence to display them in one portal as separate rows.

Alternatively, build up your list in a text field and show this field on the layout. You won't be able to mark any of the original records this way.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Since my texts are all of varying lengths and I would like to have a nice text formatting preserved, the text field seems to be the way to go. How would I build up this list? Due to the tree structure, it seems it would have to be recursive?

Comment: How many tables are we taking about? Or is it all in one table?

Comment: All in one table, self-referencing (parent_id field)

Comment: Sounds like a recursive SQL approach might work for you. Use FileMaker's ExecuteSQL function. Check out this article on the recursion which should get you started. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041814/getting-all-the-children-of-a-parent-using-mssql-query